# MySQL integer column with string search returns the invalid result

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me to understand the MySQL select query behavior,

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `dummytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mobile` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `welcome` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image]

**Question**: Why I am getting this result?

```
SELECT * FROM `dummytable` WHERE `mobile` = '\'\'' LIMIT 50
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you even trying to check if an integer column is a string?

Comment: `where mobile = ''` makes no sense at all. An integer can not contain an (empty) string. Other DBMS would simply reject to compare apples with oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column declared to be `INT` is designed to hold a number, but not a "phone number".  It can be in the range of about +/- 2 billion.

For a phone number, use `VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ascii`; that will probably be long enough (20 characters) to handle country-code, dashes, extension, and other kruft that the user might enter.

If you desire to validate that the number is a "valid" string, do that in your application code before trying to store it.